# How can I deploy an Adobe Air application including the runtime in a single file executable as a portable app?

Tags: deployment, air, desktop-application, portable-executable

I am using 7zsfx [[Link]](http://www.gdgsoft.com/faq/7zsfx.htm) to package Java apps together with a JRE as a single file executable. Is it possible to do something similar with Adobe AIR apps if I get a license from Adobe to distribute the runtime?

Also, does anybody have any alternative ideas for deploying Adobe Air apps with an embedded runtime? (Reason: Target computers may not have the Air runtime installed, and target users may not have permissions to download and install the runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

VMWare ThinApp (formerly Thinstall) and MoleBox are viable solutions *IF* they support your distribution format. They should so long as it is a PE - the Windows standard EXE/DLL form. Then they will allow installation of the runtime EVEN IF THE USER DOES NOT HAVE RIGHTS TO INSTALL IT.

I authored the first of this type product many years ago, called PEBundle. I didn't really follow up on it much, and discontinued it later. The idea is to bundle a bunch of files together, then emulate them in memory in a virtual filesystem and virtual registry (for Windows cases). So, it appears the user has full administrative rights as far as your app is concerned and the AIR runtime installs and runs great. Meanwhile, no real changes to the system occur.

However, if you work out an affordable solution, licensing may be better NOT asked about. I don't see why Adobe would really care if you redistribute their runtime, but it might better not to ask than to ask. Asking might complicate matters and get lawyers involved, when really management doesn't care. I mean, if you were in their shoes, would you care if your freely distributed runtime was redistributed by someone using it? Nah, you'd just be glad they are using AIR. If you are some lawyer, you might care because of some technicality though.

Comment: Adobe allows people to freely distribute their runtime even in external installers. You just have to fill in a webform and get permission. But, I would really want to avoid the whole install step. Like with JAVA, I'd like to copy the runtime and my air app to a temp folder, then launch the app as I can in JAVA with some equivalent code to: java -jar jar-file. (No installation - just copying and running)

Comment: I checked out VMWare ThinApp (and MoleBox). They offer an interesting solution but I think they only work on Windows. What I really need is a cross platform solution that can produce a portable app (and can be launched on Windows as single file .exe.) I've edited my question to reflect this.